# Symbol not found: _svn_auth__get_keychain_simple_provider - Bitnami Redmine

Tags: apache, redmine, bitnami

I'm trying to install Redmine on my macbook to test something
I installed Bitnami (https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine/installer) but I got error.

I tried my best but I've not found anything on Google to solve it

Error log:

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
apache config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
httpd.bin: Syntax error on line 149 of /Applications/redmine-3.3.0-2/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: dlopen(/Applications/redmine-3.3.0-2/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so, 10): Symbol not found: _svn_auth__get_keychain_simple_provider
Referenced from: /Applications/redmine-3.3.0-2/subversion/lib/libsvn_subr-1.0.dylib
Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

[image]

It said that it can not load mod_dav_svn.so because it can not found symbol `_svn_auth__get_keychain_simple_provider`

This question maybe not valid on `StackOverflow` so please comment if you think that

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami Engineer here,

There's a bug in this revision of the installer. We are working on releasing a new version of the installer without this issue. In the meantime, you can use our previous revision of the Bitnami Redmine installer: https://bitnami.com/download/files/stacks/redmine/3.3.0-1/bitnami-redmine-3.3.0-1-osx-x86_64-installer.dmg. We tested it and it works ok. Sorry for the inconvenience.